# Bring view to front in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 views, i need to add and remove another on specific conditions. Problem is, when i add both view, set constraints, and hide the one i dont need, it interrupt gestures to other view.

Is there any easy way to bring one view to front of view hierarchy, so user can interact with it? And after that, i need to do the same thing with other one view, and lower first view hierarchy priority.

In other question i heard of possibility to change Z coordinate, maybe there is a way to do that to achieve my point?

Comment: Use UIView.insertSubview(view at: position).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only modify the `zPosition` in the concept of a `CALayer`. `UIView` does not expose this functionality. It does however expose two methods; `sendSubviewToBack:` and `bringSubviewToFront:`. This would need to be called on the superview of the view you want to move, and would take the view you want to move as an argument.

Also note that if you simply set `userInteractionEnabled = false` on the top view, it will pass touches down to the view below it. This saves messing around with the view's positions.

Comment: What is the zIndex?  Never heard of...  "It does however expose two methods"  Just two?  Really?

Comment: I meant `zPosition`. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `bringSubviewToFront:` and `sendSubviewToBack:` to handle such situations. Hiding the view won't remove it from the view stack and wouldn't allow you to interact with the views below it. Hope this will help you.